# Using a skos vocabulary in an owl ontology

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, skos

I would like to refer to external skos vocabularies in an ontology. 
More precisely i would like, if possible, to state that the range of a property is one of the skos:concept defined in an existing skos vocabulary.

I think one of the problem is that in owl, a skos:concept is an individual and not a class.

I tried something like this but it is not convincing:

```
myproperty
  a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:range _:x0    .

_:x0 rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
owl:onProperty skos:inScheme  ;
owl:hasValue  theskosconceptscheme .
```

If it is possible, how could I do this properly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the [object property range axiom in OWL](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Object_Property_Range) is used to infer class membership for individuals which are objects of object properties with declared `rdfs:range`. As such it relates an object property to a class. SKOS concepts and schemes are individuals. So it is not possible to specify a concrete SKOS concept, scheme or collection as `rdfs:range` of an `owl:ObjectProperty` in OWL1. However, this is possible in OWL2, as one of the few cases where [punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning) is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Does it mean that in OWL2 the following statement is correct ?

myproperty
  a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:range skos:concept .

And is it possible to refer to a skos:concept that belongs to a specific skos:conceptScheme ?